# Error while deploying app on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am getting an error while deploying my app on google app engine:

```
Error 404: --- begin server output ---
This application does not exist (project_id=u'prob2'). To create an App Engine application in this project, run "gcloud beta app create" in your console.
--- end server output ---
2017-03-10 17:13:05 (Process exited with code 1)
```

I have tried every possible solution I found on the internet but of no use.
Please help me!

Comment: Please, show us that you have tried, how  you  deployed your app? Using [gloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/)  or another tool? Show us a bit more of code ;)

Comment: Typically the app ID in your `app.yaml` file or the deployment cmdline (`prob2`) doesn't match your real app ID or the real app doesn't yet exist.

Comment: I created an app named prob2 on google app engine. Then i created the same named app on the Google app engine launcher. But I am getting the same error. I have earlier deployed ans app named hello-udacity(without creating one on the google app engine(online)). It was simple and said hello udacity. But now i am getting the error. The project ID online is prob2-161111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

similar error occurred to me while deploying the app. i am assuming you have already setup a google cloud project on [Google's Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project) with a project id. 
Now to deploy the app, you need to install and initialize Google Cloud SDK.  Here is the [link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/) to Google Cloud SDK Documentation. 
You should be able to deploy the app now.  (bash deploy.sh project id)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try running:
`gcloud app describe --project prob2`

Depending on the result - you may just need to try what it's asking you to do....

```
gcloud config set project prob2
gcloud app create
```

Let us know what happens!

Comment: Details: [
  [
    {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ResourceInfo",
      "description": "The \"appengine.applications.get\" permission is required.",
      "resourceType": "gae.api"
    }
  ]
].......................... I am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

You need first to create your project from the **google developer console app** in the web with your unique full project id.

After that you need to **fill the project location** of deployment only after you finish that you can deploy it thru googlelaunchapp